# Separator between vertical menu items

Tags: css, menu

I'm making a vertical menu for my website. It's supposed to have a mobile look and feel. The menu is almost complete, I just don't know how to add a subtle divot/separator between each menu item. Can someone show me how this is done?

I'm styling my menu off of [JPanelMenu](http://jpanelmenu.com), so take a look if you like.

Here is the CSS for the menu:

```
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    font-family: Ubuntu;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    background: #1b1b1b;
    display: none;
    box-shadow: -0px 0px 6px #888888;
    z-index: 2;
}

#menu a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#menulinks li:hover{
    background: #6b6b6b;
}
```

You can look at my site if you need a visual demonstration. http://ion.comli.com

Comment: I can't open your right menu, it closes right away...

Comment: am also can't open menu it comes to visible and hide so please check your code it's not working properly

Comment: Fixed. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ -- This might help with your full page background issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle is here:](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/aQZAU/)

### HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Usase</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Inner-Workings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
.menu {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    max-width: 10em;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gray;
}

.menu li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.menu li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;

    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .6em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: gray;
}

.menu li:first-of-type {
    border-top: none;
}

.menu li:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.menu li a {
    /* such ugly code */ 
    background: #7f7f7f;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #7f7f7f 0%, #474747 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7f7f7f), color-stop(100%,#474747));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #7f7f7f 0%,#474747 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #7f7f7f 0%,#474747 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #7f7f7f 0%,#474747 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #7f7f7f 0%,#474747 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7f7f7f', endColorstr='#474747',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;` to either `#menu a` or `#menu li`

And if you want to avoid a separator appearing at the bottom of the last menu item, just add this:

```
#menu a:last-of-type { /* or add it to #menu li */
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because `last-of-type` is not fully supported by all browsers still in use (namely IE8). You should opt for `border-top` and target the `first-child` for border removal instead.

Comment: Fair enough, though he did say a mobile look/feel, implying IE8 is not an issue....

And really? Downvoting me because of IE8? That's low.

Comment: I can't give the vote back until you edit? Seriously? Anyways, I didn't know about Selectivizr until I got curious to see which browsers support CSS3 selectors. Mention it in your answer and I'll vote you back up...

Comment: ... pretty harsh ... I would have just noted that in the comment and attempted to provided a better solution in lieu of a down vote... just sayin.

Comment: AHAHAHAHAHAHAHA  If it doesn't work in IE, there are tons of ways to fall back, and it's just a bonus really. Graceful degradation in this case is best.